# Every real valued continuous function on a countably compact space is bounded.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove every real valued continuous function on a countably compact space is bounded.

This is the proof I have and do not understand. I would be grateful for some guidance. 
Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $k \subset X$

Then $f^{-1} (-n,n)$ is open  and $x=\cup f^{-1} (n,-n)$.

Then there is a countable subcover  $x \subset f^{-1} (-n_1 , n_1) \cup ...f^{-1} (-n_s, n_s)$

We can say $f \subset f^{-1} (-N,N)$ where $N=$max$(n_1,n_2,...,n_s)$

Meaning that $-N < f(x) < N$ as required.

In this proof why do we consider the inverse of f?

Why is $f \subset f^{-1} (-N,N)$?

Comment: Are you aware of the definition for compactness that "every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover"?

Comment: Note that given $f:X \to Y$ and a set $S\subset Y$, we define
$$
f^{-1}(S) = \{x \in X: f(x) \in S\}
$$
that is what they mean by $f^{-1}(-n,n)$

Comment: Please improve your formatting. What is $k$? What is $x$? You keep using the symbol $ \subset$ where it isn't appropriate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me write your proof a bit more clearly:

The intervals  $(-n,n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$  is an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$. Thus $\cup_n f^{-1}((-n,n) ) = f^{-1}(\cup_n(-n,n) )=  X$ is an open cover of $X$ (note that the inverse image of an open set under a continuous map is open).

This is a covering by countably many sets. Therefore, as $X$ is countably compact, it has a **finite** subcover. This means $\cup_{i=1}^k f^{-1}((-n_i,n_i) ) =  X$ for some $k$ and $n_i$.

Applying $f$ we get $\cup_{i=1}^k (-n_i,n_i)  \supset  f(X)$.

Setting $N$ the maximum of the $n_i$ one has $f(X) \subset (-N,N)$, which shows that $|f(x)| \le N$ for each $x \in X$ that is $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

This proof produces a countable collection of open sets that covers $X$, and so by countable compactness there is a finite subcollection that covers $X$.

These open sets have the property that the image of each of them is contained in a bounded interval. So the image of $X$ is contained in a finite union of bounded intervals, which is also bounded.

You use the inverse of $f$ to pull open sets in the range (the open intervals $(-n,n)$) back to open sets in the domain (the open sets $f^{-1}((-n,n))$). That's where continuity is used (recall: $f:A\to B$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$ whenever $U$ is open in $B$; that's usually the *definition* of continuity).